# Login facebook with ParseFacebookUtil.login() return null user and exception invalid date

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I followed instruction to setup my android project with correct app_id, parse_app_id, parse_client_id. And even using [ParseUI for Android](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android) to sign up a new account & logged-in. But facebook login just doesn't work!

Here's my settings(UPDATED to Parse-1.9.1 & Facebook v4.0.1):

In my app the build.gradle:

```
compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
```

In the ParseLoginUI project its build.gradle(not change just copied from repo):

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'

        provided 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
        // This assumes that your app's project has a compile dependency on the Parse SDK JAR files.
        // Your project's build.gradle should say:
        //
        //     compile files('YOUR_PROJECT_LIBS_PATH/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
        //     compile files('YOUR_PROJECT_LIBS_PATH/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
        //
        // Since the dependency below is "provided" instead of "compile", your project's build.gradle
        // does not have to refer to the same Parse SDK instance that's in the ParseLoginUI/libs folder.
        provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseLoginUI/libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar")
        provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseLoginUI/libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar")
    }
```

Clicking login button will run:

```
facebookLoginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_auth_button);
facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        onLoadingListener.onLoadingStart(false); // Facebook login pop-up already has a spinner

        if (config.isFacebookLoginNeedPublishPermissions()) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
                    config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
        } else {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
                    config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
        }
    }
});

private LogInCallback facebookLoginCallbackV4 = new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (isActivityDestroyed()) {
            return;
        }

        if (user == null) {
            //loadingFinish();
            if (e != null) {
                Logger.d(getString(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_facebook_login_failed) +
                        e.toString());
            }
            UIUtils.getSoldaToast(
                    getActivity(),
                    getString(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_facebook_login_failed_toast),
                    Gravity.CENTER).show();
        } else if (user.isNew()) {
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject fbUser,
                                                GraphResponse response) {
              /*
                If we were able to successfully retrieve the Facebook
                user's name, let's set it on the fullName field.
              */
                            ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                            if (fbUser != null && parseUser != null
                                    && fbUser.optString("name").length() > 0) {
                                parseUser.put(USER_OBJECT_NAME_FIELD, fbUser.optString("name"));
                                parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e != null) {
                                            Logger.d(getString(
                                                    com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_facebook_login_user_update_failed) +
                                                    e.toString());
                                        }
                                        loginSuccess();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            loginSuccess();
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
        } else {
            loginSuccess();
        }
    }
};
```

It always return null user & ParseException said invalid date:

[image: error-code-107]

checkout the [doc](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm) but still don't know what I did wrong.

BTW, I'm sure I DO comment out `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` to make it's not because of [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/229876443869758/). And the only facebook permission I request is `email` so the call would be

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(
        getActivity(),
        config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), 
        facebookLoginCallbackV4
);
```

After update to latest version of ParseUI-android, the issue still occur.

Anyone experience this?

Comment: Do you see the same error using the latest SDK? Could be a bug, you can [report it](https://parse.com/help).

Comment: did you find the solution of this problem ??

Comment: Glad to hear someone ask...but no. Is there any way I can just use pure Facebook SDK for facebook login & Parse SDK for email sign up/login? I hate them mixed up and make the apk fat.

Comment: I've updated to Parse-1.9.1 & Facebook sdk v4.0.1. The issue still occur! I can't even login with the sample app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this solved! Friend suggest me to `delete the app from my facebook account` to make sure starting fresh. And then uninstall the Android app to re-install again. BOOOM! it works! Thank you Faceboooook.

Hope this helps!